# Lock statement - does it always release the lock?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have recently read [this post from Eric Lippert regarding the lock implementation in c#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix.aspx) and still some questions remain.

In 4.0 implementation if a thread abort or any cross thread exception occurs just before the Monitor.Exit(temp) in the finally block is executed - would that keep the lock on the object?

Is there any possibility for an exception to occur at this level, leaving the object still in a locked state?

Comment: You can try this yourself. Use `Monitor.Enter` to lock an object on a different thread, call `Thread.Abort` and see if another thread can enter a lock on that object.

Comment: Thread.Abort propergates the exception up the stack and executes finally blocks before the CLR terminates the thread.

Comment: Would Thread.Abort be the only case to worry about with cross thread exceptions? An OutOfMemory or any unmanaged exceptions that could keep the CLR process running but only killing this thread at this precise point?

Comment: In both cases the execution stopped at unspecified points while mutating some state (if not why the hell were you holding a lock? ). The only reasonable choice here is to abort otherwise you'll just do more harm than good

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> In 4.0 implementation if a thread abort or any cross thread exception occurs just before the `Monitor.Exit(temp)` in the finally block is executed - would that keep the lock on the object?

Let's take a look at that code, so that it is clear to other readers:

```
bool lockWasTaken = false;
var temp = obj;
try 
{ 
  Monitor.Enter(temp, ref lockWasTaken); 
  { 
    body 
  } 
}
finally 
{ 
  if (lockWasTaken) 
  {
    // What if a thread abort happens right here?
    Monitor.Exit(temp); 
  }
}
```

Your question is not answerable because it is based on a false assumption, namely, that thread aborts can happen in the middle of a finally block.

Thread aborts cannot happen in the middle of a finally block. That is just one reason amongst many reason why you should never attempt to abort a thread. The entire thread could be running in a finally block, and therefore be not-abortable.

> Is there any possibility for an exception to occur at this level, leaving the object still in a locked state?

No. A thread abort will be delayed until control leaves the finally. Unlocking a valid lock does not allocate memory or throw another exception.

Answer (score 9):

Read up about [`ThreadAbortException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx):

> When this exception is raised, the runtime executes all the **finally** blocks before ending the thread

(This includes any `finally` block that is *currently* executing when `Thread.Abort` is called)

So yes, the lock will be released still. Whether this is desirable or not is a very different matter though - you don't know that the thread is just about to release the lock - it could be anywhere, and may be in the middle of mutating the state that the lock was protecting - so as always, the advice is to avoid `Thread.Abort`.

Comment: Could you have a look at my comment above? I know it's pretty vague question but I would like to understand all the possible cases

Comment: @Rod - OutOfMemory is a bit of a pain to reason about because if any of the code in your finally block wants to allocate then obviously that will fail. But I'd have thought that the unlock code for a `lock` statement falls into the set of code that's unlikely to allocate. I can't think of any situation where the unlock will fail, and think it far more likely that you'll win the lottery two weeks running or generate two identical GUIDs on two separate machines.

Comment: Releasing a valid lock does not ever fail and it does not allocate memory.

Comment: Your answer gets across the right idea but the key bit of reasoning that you might want to emphasize is: **if a finally block is already running then the thread abort exception is delayed until it finishes**.

Comment: @EricLippert If you are getting OutOfMemoryException, you have bigger problems. Finding ways to handle that gracefully is wasted effort - cure it instead or you will always see side effects.

Comment: @EricLippert - yes, I was kind of switching between talking about the general case of "will every finally block definitely run" and the specific case of "will the finally block that releases the lock definitely run" but was trying to avoid getting into e.g. constrained execution regions. I could probably have made it clearer.

Comment: @Gusdor In almost all cases, you would be right. But I can imagine that there are some extremely rare situations where handling OOM is the right thing to do. And if the user can do this, the language/runtime should not hinder him by doing something stupid like allocating memory when releasing a lock.